# How to make a cell automatically parse data upon input

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Right now I'm trying to make a simple script that will give the optimal time to shoot when pasting the coordinates of the two people.

[image]

I want someone to be able to just paste a string of three coordinates separated by spaces into B3 and C3 so that the excel sheet will automatically parse the data into the x, y, and z cells on the same row. I know the text to column feature works really well and is easy, but I would like to make it as easy as possible for someone to run the program just by copy and pasting data like -2189 261 -95 so that it will fill into the cells.

Would this be possible? Would I have to use a script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need are string-parsing formulas in D3:F3.

For the *x*-coordinate, in D3 enter the formula:

```
=VALUE(LEFT($B3,FIND(" ",$B3)-1))
```

For the *y*-coordinate, in E3 enter the formula:

```
=VALUE(MID($B3,FIND(" ",$B3),FIND(" ",$B3,FIND(" ",$B3)+1)-FIND(" ",$B3)))
```

For the *z*-coordinate, in F3 enter the formula:

```
=VALUE(MID($B3,FIND(" ",$B3,FIND(" ",$B3)+1)+1,LEN($B3)))
```

These will return an error when the data is not present in B3. You may want to wrap these functions in an `IFERROR(..., "")` to make them show as blank when there is no input data.

Also, just to make sure there's no funny business, you can add data validation to the input cell to alert you if the input is not formatted properly.

Comment: Thanks! I find that the z coordinate only sometimes works. I'm not familiar with the value function so I'm not sure how I would modify it to fully function. Is there anything in particular that could mess with the z function?

Comment: Share a case where it doesn't work: what's the input, the expected output, and the actual output?

Comment: -2189.514404 261.389465 -95.906189 outputs the #VALUE error, expecting a -95.91

Comment: I can't recreate that error. Perhaps you have multiple spaces between the values?

Comment: Ah, I had extra space at the end. My bad!